# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadException

Tags: java, spring-mvc, websphere-liberty, apache-commons-fileupload

I have created a Spring MVC Maven project in which I have added a [commons-fileupload 1.4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.4) dependency.

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
         <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Moreover I have added the bean reference for Multipart resolver into my Spring configuration file:

```
<bean name="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="5252880"></property>
</bean>
```

I've checked into my local repository for corresponding jar files and they are present however when I deploy my project into Websphere Liberty server I'm getting the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory

What am I doing wrong in adding the missing dependency?

Comment: Try to add commons-io as a dependency with the corresponding version

Comment: Clear your repository and re-download the dependencies.

Comment: I've tryed to add the latest commons-io library as a dependency into my project whithout any effect :-(

Comment: After mvn-clear, mvn-install it seems to work. Updating Maven project it wasn't enough.

Comment: @M. Deinum
Thanks :-)